# How to split string if it is followed by two or more space/whitespace in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

In my string, i want to split the string or tokenize string on the basis of two or more spaces.

E.x.

```
string = "I am  Chaitanya Gadam.      Split   this srting."
```

i want output as -

```
str[0]= "I am"  
str[1]= "Chaitanya Gadam."  
str[2]= "Split"  
str[3]= "this string."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.split("\\s\\s+");
```

(or)

```
string.split("\\s{2,}");

 String string = "I am  Chaitanya Gadam.      Split   this srting.";

    String[] str = string.split("\\s{2,}");

    for(String s: str)
    {
        System.out.println(s+":"+s.length());
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.split("\\s\\s+")));

Output:
I am:4
Chaitanya Gadam.:16
Split:5
this srting.:12
[I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.]
```

Splits strings with two or more spaces as delimiter. Using Escape character in the Regex increases readability instead of using space character.

Comment: Sunny, can we have out put like, [I am] [  ] [Chaitanya Gadam.] [     ] [split] [   ] [this string.]

Answer (score 2):

Try using: `String[] splitted = string.split("  +");`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
    String string = "I am  Chaitanya Gadam.      Split   this srting.";
    String[] str = string.split("  +");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
    for(String s : str)//Try printing this way .
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
[I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.]
```

Comment: Hello Achintya, i tried it but it is not giving me desired output.

Comment: Why we are getting  space before each token?

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadam There is no space or comma. try printing using for loop.

Comment: [I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.] i think you are talking about the extra space in this output. it is just the tostring representation of string array.

Comment: Yes, what if i don't want that extra space?

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadam **There's no extra space!**

Comment: Another problem is that if my string have extra white space at the begining then i get output as, final String src = " I am Chaitanya Gadam. Split this srting."; [, I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.]
but reqiured output is [I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.] So i am trying to use string tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this should work:

```
final String src = "I am  Chaitanya Gadam.      Split   this srting.";
final String[] splits = src.split("[ ]{2,}");
```

Comment: Got- [I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.]  Why we are getting space before each token?

Comment: Downvoting because you didn't understand how to print the output is just plain wrong. Here is the [Ideone](http://ideone.com/FYqvGF).

Comment: print the array in for loop you wont have any space infront of each token. dont just downvote

Comment: final String[] splits = src.split("[ ]{1,}"); This would be correct :)

Comment: @MohanRajB - no, thats not correct (you can try it yourself).

Comment: Another problem is that if my string have extra white space at the begining then i get output as,

    final String src = "         I am  Chaitanya Gadam.      Split   this srting.";    
    [, I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.]

Answer (score 0):

Use Stringutils.split() to split the string by whites paces. For example `StringUtils.split("Hello World")` returns "Hello" and "World";

In order to solve the mentioned case we use split method like this

```
String split[]= StringUtils.split("Hello I'm your String");
```

when we print the split array the output will be :

```
Hello

I'm

your

String
```

The only problem is if you try split `string = "I am  Chaitanya Gadam.      Split   this srting."`

It will split Chiatanya Gadam. Into

```
[0]Chiatanya
[1]Gadam.
```

But you can combine it later!